# How to limit user access to `gvfs-mount`? How to set `rw` permissions on a device mountpoint when using `gvfs-mount`?

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, gvfs

Setup:  Ubuntu 16.04.03 with Unity I/F

The HAL-based /etc/fstab system for mounting devices offers superuser-only operation security and also allows setting read and write properties per mountpoint (cf. [fstab man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/fstab.5.html)).

On the other hand, according to [this `gvfs-mount` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gvfs-mount.1.html):

```
   gvfs-mount provides commandline access to various aspects of GIOs
   mounting functionality.
   Mounting refers to the traditional concept of arranging multiple file
   systems and devices in a single tree, rooted at /. Classical mounting
   happens in the kernel and is controlled by the mount utility. GIO
   expands this concept by introducing mount daemons that can make file
   systems available to GIO applications without kernel involvement.
```

**Is there a way to specify superuser-only permission to invoke `gvfs-mount`, either for all devices or per-device?  And a way to set read and write permission on a device mountpoint when using `gvfs-mount`?**

*Aside: If not, why not?*

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: @muru - For security reasons, keep some devices selectively mounted/ selectively readable.  E.g., an internal sata disk or an external usb device which does not usually need to be mounted and never needs to be visible expect to su.
Notably, those cases were included in the HAL-fstab interface specs, but are overruled by presence of gvfs-mount.
Presumably that part of the interface was duly considered and then deemed obsolete, but I can't find that reasoning on the web or in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, `gvfs-mount` uses `udisks2` for volume monitoring of ["local" devices](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs/doc#Volume_monitors):

> Volume monitors provide a set of `GDrive`/`GVolume`/`GMount` objects
>   representing physical device or service hierarchy. So called native
>   volume monitors provide access to locally available devices, i.e.
>   those appearing in /dev and mountable by standard POSIX ways (`mount`,
>   `umount`). GVfs provides several implementations of those (hal, gdu,
>   udisks2) and only one can be active.

You can control access to udisks2 using Polkit rules. The relevant polkit actions are:

```
$ pkaction| grep mount
org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount
org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-other-seat
org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system
org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-unmount-others
```

You can require admin access via a Polkit rule like so (say in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/disable-mount.pkla`):

```
[Disable mount]
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem*
Identity=*
ResultActive=auth_admin
ResultAny=auth_admin
ResultInactive=auth_admin
```

This would mean that users would need Polkit admin privileges (by default, group `sudo` or the root user in Ubuntu). A prompt like this will be shown:

[image]

polkit 0.106 adds support for JavaScript rules, which means you can set more nuanced permissions, but that version is [not yet available in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-1/+bug/1086783).

Presumably `gvfs-mount` leaves the actual read/write permissions to the mount backend.

That said, rules in `/etc/fstab` still take priority over whatever `gvfs-mount` does. With this rule for `/dev/sdb` in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb /mnt   ext4 ro,noexec 0 0
```

`gvfs-mount` simply throws an error and `udisksctl` mounts using the `fstab` rule:

```
$ gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdb
No volume for device file /dev/sdb
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb
Mounted /dev/sdb at /mnt.
```

Of course, `udisksctl` asked for Polkit authorization, since I had created the `pkla` file mentioned earlier.

Comment: Hi muru - Thank you very much for your detailed answer.  It worked perfectly for the access issue - although I must admit I just copied and pasted into the designated localtion, I didn't really research the background.
As far as read/write permission goes, couldn't modifiy the gvfs-modity created directories, not even as su.  And gvsf is clever enough to add numbers to those names when the name is already taken.  (For that same reason I suspect using the gvsf preferred names as destination in fstab might not work. )

Comment: In the end I managed the rw permissions by gaining control further up the directory path. 
As for using fstab to interrupt control by gvsf, setting the source as /dev/bydisk/by-uuid/<uuid>  would indeed be worth a try.  However, right now with the other ad hoc methods it's enough.